# Scrapy - How do i extract info from nested links

Tags: python, scrapy, href, scrape, rule

I'm starting to learn how to use Scrapy [www.scrapy.org](http://www.scrapy.org).

My problem is that I'm trying to extract information from a link inside another link.

The flow is like this:

We enter **www.imdb.com**, then on the menu click on Watchlist > IMDbtop250, after that we will end up in **http://www.imdb.com/chart/top** where we will find a list of movies;

I'm trying to enter each movie which has a link like this `www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2398042102&pf_rd_r=1EX7BT4EGCE6HVGF919H&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_1` and then enters full cast link from movie that looks like this `www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast`, and starts extracting all the actors from the last link, so the problem is that I know how to extract the info but struggling with the navigation of the links, this is the code I have right now

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import item
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class ActorsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "actors"
    allowed_domains = ["www.imdb.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.imdb.com/chart/top',
                  'http://www.imdb.com/title/']

    def parse(self, response):
        rules = {
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/title/tt0111161/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2398042102&pf_rd_r=0BP5GZ1CWDNT2NFAWKDN&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_1')),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast'), callback='parse_actor'),
        }

    def parse_actor(self, response):
        item['title'] = response.css('title').extract()[0]
        return item
```

I'm aware that this is supposed to be done in a recursive way but first I'm actually trying to make the links work, and that both links I'm trying to enter share this characteristic `/title/tt0111161/` at least for the first link.

Also, I'm just extracting title, for now, to know if I am where I want to be.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Removed some links because I don't have 10 reputation YET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your allowed_domains is wrong, it must be :

```
allowed_domains = ["imdb.com"]
```

Start with the top rated movies

```
start_urls = ['http://www.imdb.com/chart/top/']
```

Parse each movie and prepare the url for the actors list

```
def parse(self, response):
        for film in response.css('.titleColumn'):
            url = film.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            actors_url = 'http://imdb.com' + url[:17] + 'fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast'
            yield scrapy.Request(actors_url, self.parse_actor)
```

Then find all actors

```
def parse_actor(self, response):
        item = ImdbItem()
        item['title'] = response.css('h3[itemprop~=name] a::text').extract_first()
        item['actors'] = response.css('td[itemprop~=actor] span::text').extract()
        return item
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, now ill just update to also add the poster in my JSON object, by the way, can you explain how `h3[itemprop~=name] a::text` works, I understand that itemProp is not equal to name?

Comment: You can use `scrapy shell (link)`

Comment: My question was about the ~= operator